# Get the touch shape in android

Tags: android, touch

I am creating a application in which i want to draw the shape of touch event in my screen.Any ApI to get the shape of the touch event particularly?

Any examples or code snippets is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Narayan

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ? Highlight on screen the area touched by the user ?

Comment: ya with the shape of the touch area and not by circle or any other shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet should achieve what you want:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new DrawingView(this));
    }

    class DrawingView extends SurfaceView {

        private final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private final Path path = new Path();
        private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        public DrawingView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            surfaceHolder = getHolder();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                    Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```